# Rails: form_for shortening code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb, form-for, templating

I am currently learning rails and I have the following code:

```
<%= form_for(@account) do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :username %>
  <%= f.text_field :username, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :email %>    
   <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control'  %>


  <%= f.label :password %>
  <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control'  %>

  <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirm your password" %>
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control'  %>

  <%= f.label :website %>
  <%= f.text_field :website, class: 'form-control'  %>

  <%= f.submit "Sign up!", class: "btn btn-primary" %>

<% end %>
```

I want to add glyphicons, so the code for one of the fields(:email) looks like so:

```
  <div class="input-group"> 
      <div class="input-group-addon"> 
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> 
      </div> 

      <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control'  %>
  </div>
```

The trouble is, I want to do this for all the fields.

But then I'd have to copy-and-paste these same statements for all the fields, changing glyphicon-* and the field name (and field type for password fields). Is there a simpler DRY way to do this?

Comment: You could define a method in a view helper method, pass some arguments to it and return the custom HTML from there.

Comment: Thanks, I did it your way and it works. For anyone out there: Use raw() method to return your custom HTML from the helper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alon Swain method is also correct, but I would suggest to use separate partial instead let say `_input_field_password.html.erb`

```
<div class="input-group"> 
  <div class="input-group-addon"> 
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> 
  </div> 

  <%= f.email_field field_name, class: 'form-control'  %>
 </div>
```

Now change your form.erb

```
<%= form_for(@account) do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :username %>
  <%= render partial 'input_field_password.html.erb', locals: {f: f, field_name: :user_name}%>

  <%= f.label :email %>    
  <%= render partial 'input_field_password.html.erb', locals: {f: f, field_name: :email} %>


  <%= f.label :password %>
  <%= render partial 'input_field_password.html.erb', locals: {f: f, field_name: :password}%>

  <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirm your password" %>
  <%= render partial 'input_field_password.html.erb', locals: {f: f, field_name: :password_confirmation}%>

  <%= f.label :website %>
  <%= render partial 'input_field_password.html.erb', locals: {f: f, field_name: :website}%>

  <%= f.submit "Sign up!", class: "btn btn-primary" %>

<% end %>
```

You could also refactor it further using loop

```
<%= form_for(@account) do |f| %>
  <% [:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :website].each do |field_name|
    <%= f.label :field_name %>
    <%= render partial 'input_field_password.html.erb', locals: {f: f, field_name: :field_name}%>
  <%end%>
  <%= f.submit "Sign up!", class: "btn btn-primary" %>

<% end %>
```

Comment: Good answer! I used your method in combination with Alon Swain to make the code look a lot nicer!